# Implementing Computer Vison on AutoML to classify dementia using MRI images in .NII file format

Tags: python-3.x, computer-vision, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-auto-ml

I am using .NII file format which represents, the neuroimaging dataset. I need to use Auto ML to label the dataset of images that are nearly 2GB in size per patient. The main issue is with using Auto ML to label the dataset of images with.NII file extension and classify whether the patient is having dementia or not.

**Requirement:** Forget about the problem domain of implementation like dementia. I would like to know about the procedure of using Auto ML for Computer vision applications through ML studio to use.NII file format dataset images.

Any help would be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement of using .nii or other file formats in Azure auto ML is a challenging task. Unfortunately, Auto ML image input format will be using in only JSON format. Kindly check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/reference-automl-images-schema)

Answering regarding requirement of .nii format of dataset, there are different file format convertors available like "***[Medical Image Convertor](http://medicalimageconverter.com/?msclkid=403b597ecf8111ecac65b3422c7b95b5)***". This software is commercial and can be used for 10days for free. Convert .nii file formats into JPG and proceed with the general documentation provided in the top of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I downloaded the software and tried to convert one. It worked fine for me. It's time to use AutoML and check. @SairamTadepalli-MT thanks and it worked.